Strange SPI Flash Memory Behavior
I'm working on a project in which I use the W25Q128JVSIQ flash memory chip from Winbond to store audio data that will later be output to a speaker. The memory chip interfaces to an STM32 microcontroller through a basic full-duplex SPI interface.
I'm waiting for my PCBs to arrive and am writing a driver for the chip right now with a NUCLEO development board and breadboard connections to the memory chip.
My pin connections are as follows:

Pin 1 - nCS (MCU GPIO)
Pin 2 - MISO (MCU Pin)
Pin 3 - nWP, pulled directly to VCC
Pin 4 - GND
Pin 5 - MOSI (MCU Pin)
Pin 6 - CLK (MCU Pin)
Pin 7 - nHOLD, pulled directly to VCC
Pin 8 - VCC (3.3V)

I have continuity-checked all of these connections. I have taken voltage measurements at all DC nodes (VCC, GND, nWP, nHOLD) and verified that the voltages are correct. I have also looked at all SPI signals on an oscilloscope and verified that they are correct in terms of clock polarity, rising/falling edge data alignment, chip select high/low, and that the SPI outputs from the MCU match the timing diagrams shown in the datasheet for the W25Q128JVSIQ chip.
Despite all of this, I'm seeing bizarre behavior on the MISO line of the memory chip.
For example, when sending a command to read status register 2 from the chip, the output looks as follows:

Yellow is the SPI CLK, blue is the SPI MOSI. Unfortunately, I don't have a higher-channel scope or logic analyzer, else I'd show all 4 SPI signals.
Note the little impulse in the MOSI signal - here's a zoomed-in image:

I expect this register data to return 0b00000010, and the SPI samples on the rising edge of the clock. Therefore, it looks as if the MOSI line is trying to go high for that single bit, but gets cut off for some reason. I see these impulses in the bit positions that I expect to be high for other read commands as well.
I don't know what could be causing this. I used a multimeter to check for shorts to VCC/GND or other pins, but found none. I also increased the driver strength of the chip to 100%, but this seems to have no effect.
If that wasn't complicated enough, the chip seems to return correct data once in a blue moon. I can't recreate it, but when it does, high bits look like decent square waves, albeit with an amplitude of ~2.72V.
I can include my code if needed, but this seems like a hardware issue. Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?

Yes we do but you aren't showing the hardware either, no schematics or PCB or airwiring. The code may be important as well. Or you have initialized the STM32 SPI to use SS hardware handshaking or otherwise incorrectly. Please add schematics and code, picture of current hardware setup etc.

Closing until additional info is provided (please edit)
